# Page loading different JS scripts when loaded from different parent page

Tags: oracle-apex

I have several pages on my apex app, with similar information. When I click on a record, it calls another page with some detail info. The page for detail info is always the same. However when being called from different pages, it loads different JS scripts. In some pages it only loads two script but in some pages it's up to 50 JS scripts, making it very slow to load. Why is this? I didn't put those scripts, apex put them there.

I have checked that all pages have the same attributes and they all are basically a copy from each other, the only thing that changes is the info shown.
I'm using Oracle Apex 19.1.0.00.15.

Comment: How is it you know these "JS scripts" are slowing page load? Are you talking files, or code? Each page will have different components, requiring different JS needs. Dynamic Actions will generate plenty of embedded JS code.

Comment: Because I saw it on the network tab on Dev Tools from browser. I know each page will have different components, but in this case, it's the same page, but called from a different parent page.